# How to stop Angular $timeout when bootstrap modal opens and resume after the modal closes?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code that fetches data from db every 1 second:

```
app.controller("rfController", ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.displayData = function () {

        $http.get('db.php').success(function(data) {
            $scope.refreshes = data;
            console.log(data);
        });

        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.displayData();
        },1000)

    };

}]);
```

But the problem is that I have some buttons that open up bootstrap modals to look into these data. When I open the modal, it keeps closing because the displayData() function keeps refreshing. Here is the html for modal:

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-right">
    <button class="btn rf-btn" id="clicked" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rfmodal{{$index}}">More</button> <!-- OPENS MODAL -->
    <!-- MODAL -->
    <div class="modal small fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="rfmodal{{$index}}">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" 
                    ng-class="{'bg-success': refresh.status === 'Successful',
                                'bg-fail': refresh.status === 'Failed',
                                'bg-delay': refresh.status === 'Delayed'}">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center">{{refresh.company}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body text-left">
                    <p class="detail-text"><b>Status</b>: {{refresh.status}}</p>
                    <p class="detail-text"><b>TimeStamp</b>: {{refresh.dt}}</p>
                    <p class="detail-text"><b>OrgID</b>: {{refresh.orgid}}</p>
                    <p class="detail-text"><b>Body</b>: {{refresh.body}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button rf-btn" class="btn rf-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In controller your variable name is $scope.refreshes.
In html you are fetching data from  "refresh" .Could be a problem??

Also $timeout delays the execution of the function, it won't repeatedly call the displaydata function every 1 second.It will only call it once after a second.

You should use $interval instead.

Comment: Right. It's meant to do that. Wait 1 second and execute displayData() itself again. So it works the same way. $scope.refreshes is not an issue because i'm doing ng-repeat = refresh in refreshes. But the problem is not the refresh - more of a modal issue... the auto refreshes must stop once the modal is opened and resume when it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. This will stop the interval when modal is open.

> And you have to use setInterval to call the function repeatedly ,
>   $timeout only executes once after given time.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <body>

                <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="rfController">

                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                        <button class="btn rf-btn" id="clicked" ng-click="runInterval = false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rfmodal{{$index}}" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">More</button> <!-- OPENS MODAL -->
                        <!-- MODAL -->
                        <div class="modal small fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="rfmodal{{$index}}">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header" 
                                    ng-class="{'bg-success': refresh.status === 'Successful',
                                    'bg-fail': refresh.status === 'Failed',
                                    'bg-delay': refresh.status === 'Delayed'}">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center">{{refresh.company}}</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body text-left">
                                    <p class="detail-text"><b>Status</b>: {{refresh.status}}</p>
                                    <p class="detail-text"><b>TimeStamp</b>: {{refresh.dt}}</p>
                                    <p class="detail-text"><b>OrgID</b>: {{refresh.orgid}}</p>
                                    <p class="detail-text"><b>Body</b>: {{refresh.body}}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button rf-btn" class="btn rf-btn" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="runInterval = true">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                app.controller("rfController", ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
                    $scope.runInterval = true;

                    $scope.displayData = function () {
                        $http.get('http://localhost').success(function(data) {
                            $scope.refreshes = data;
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                        console.log("displayData");
                    };

                    setInterval(function() {
                        if($scope.runInterval){
                            $scope.displayData();
                            console.log("Done");
                        }
                    },1000)

                }]);
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: The problem is not executing the refreshes. The problem is that the refresh doesn't stop when I open my modal. Any ideas?

Comment: In your code, how does angular know that the modal is opened?

Comment: This should use `$interval` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: Check the button code, I'm applying a variable to that , when you click open modal button that variable goes "false", so the interval stops, when you close the modal I'm again setting that variable true, so interval starts running again.